# mySQL syntax creating/dropping unique index, using "name" vs "column"

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm encountering a particular edge case in mySQL. I have the following table:

```
SHOW TABLE CREATE users;
```

Output:

```
users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serial` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `version` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Key Number / version',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serial` (`serial`, `version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7078 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm not able to understand from syntax whether:

- I have two uniques keys, one only on column `serial` and one on columns `(serial, version)`
- Or, I have one unique key on columns `(serial, version)`, of name `serial`

When I try adding a row which a duplicate key `serial` (but not same version), sometimes it allows me, and sometimes I get an error on `duplicate key serial`. It's not deterministic.

Anyhow, beside what I have now, my goal is to have just ONE unique key on columns `(serial, version)`. So I tried running:

```
ALTER TABLE users DROP INDEX serial;
```

This, to my surprise, removes BOTH unique keys and not just the one columns, as if in fact that was a name and not a constraint itself.

So which is what? If that's only a name, why doesn't it allow me multiple rows with same `serial` (and different `version`)?  How can I achieve that?
Could someone clarify how to understand this?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example. The [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) is clear: `[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX | KEY] [index_name] [index_type] (key_part,...)`. It is a multi column index

Comment: What you describe is the expected behaviour. The unique index in your question applies to the combination of two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the create table statement you posted above:

You got one primary key, making the column 'id' unique,
meaning every record must have a different id.

And a unique key named 'serial', which makes columns named
'serial' and 'version' unique as a combination.

So you can have infinite records/rows with diffrent versions for example,
as long that record has a different 'serial' assigned.

You can also look up names of your index with

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE;
```